# Adding Copyright metadata details to media files in Windows 10

Tags: metadata

Window10 gives users the access to add/edit metadata to media files(video,audio etc) by accesing it's properties (file - rightclick -properties),but it does not allow the ability to **add Copyright information** for the file.

How can one override this limitation?

[image: Copyright Metadata]